# Perspective transform with perspective origin in OpenGL/GLKit

Tags: ios, opengl-es, matrix

I'm creating a simple grid of squares using OpenGL, and I would like it so that when the user taps on a square it flips over (I have this code working) on the Y axis. However because the perspective origin/vanishing point is at the center of the screen, the rotation doesn't appear to be relative to the center of the square as it should be.

Below is an image of all of the squares rotated by 0.5 radians (about 30 degrees). The central square is correctly rotated, however I would like all of the other squares to have their perspective relative to their central point, rather than the central point of the screen (currently they appear sheered, which I don't want):

[image]

Here's how I create the projection & view matrices (applies to all the squares):

```
float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
_projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);
_viewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0, 0, -5);
```

And here's how I create a model matrix for each square:

```
GLKMatrix4 modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(tile.x, tile.y, 0);
modelMatrix = GLKMatrix4RotateY(modelMatrix, 0.5f);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with this I eventually ended up looking how CSS3 transforms are implemented, and [W3C provides the following explanation of how perspective-origin should be computed](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#perspective-matrix-computation):

> 1. Start with the identity matrix.
> 2. Translate by the computed X and Y values of perspective-origin
> 3. Multiply by the matrix that would be obtained from the perspective() transform function, where the length is provided by the value of the perspective property
> 4. Translate by the negated computed X and Y values of perspective-origin

This is fairly easy to apply to OpenGL and GLKit. Rather than multiplying Projection * View * Model (and in this case my model transform is a translation and rotation) I found that multiplying Translation * Projection * View * Rotation instead does the job, and allows me to flip the squares around their center properly.